Argue whether the generalized double integral $\int \int_D \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ where $D$ is $x\geq1 , y\geq1$ converge or diverge.
In the first part of the problem, I proved that
$$ \int_1^\infty (\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy)dx $$
and
$$ \int_1^\infty (\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dx)dy $$
converge, $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
The second part of the problem is whether this result is enough to show that
$$\int \int_D \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}dxdy\ \text{where}\  D\  \text{is}\  x\geq1 , y\geq1$$
also converges. I am tempted to use the comparison criteria but the domain not being a circle confuses me as to what I should use as comparison.

First, we can show that $f$ is not absolutely integrable over $D$.
Defining $E = \{(x,y): x\geqslant 1, y\geqslant 1, x^2+y^2 \geqslant 1\}$, we have $E \subset D$. Since $|f|$ is nonnegative we can choose the sequence $A_n = \{ (x,y): x \geqslant 1, y\geqslant 1, 1 \leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant n\}$ to obtain
$$\int_D |f|\geqslant \int_E |f|= \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{A_n} |f| $$
Since $A_n$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous, we can evaluate the Riemann integral over $A_n$as an iterated integral and change to polar coordinates. Hence,
$$\int_{A_n} |f|= \int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\int_1^n\frac{|(r\cos\theta)^2 - (r\sin \theta)^2|}{|(r\cos\theta)^2 + (r\sin \theta)^2|}\,r\, dr\right) \, d\theta\\= \int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\int_1^n|\cos^2\theta - \sin^2 \theta|\,r\, dr\right) \, d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2} |\cos(2\theta)|\, d\theta\int_1^n r\, dr= \frac{n^2-1}{2}\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow+\infty,$$
and, thus, $\int_D|f|  = +\infty$ and the improper integral of $|f|$ diverges.
We can also show that the integral of $f$ over $D$ is not even conditionally convergent.  We can find sequences $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ such that
$$\int_{A_n}f \to 0, \quad \int_{B_n} f \to +\infty$$
An example of the first case is $A_n = \{(x,y): 1\leqslant x\leqslant n,1\leqslant y\leqslant n\}$.

The last integral is probably divergent.
An informal reasoning show that even with $y$ bounded (i.e. $\int_1^M \cdots dy$) and $x\gg 1$ (you can as well take $\int_{2M}^\infty\cdots dx$) then you get $x^2-y^2\ge \frac 12x^2$ and $x^2+y^2\le 2x^2$
So this contribution is $\ge \frac 14$ and since summed to infinity diverges.
